# How to properly bind a DependencyProperty to a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am beginner to WPF and I am facing problem while trying to bind a Dependency Property as the source of a `CollectionViewSource`.

The user control exposes a `DependencyProperty` of type `List`. It is used to present the data in a `DataGrid` with the help of `CollectionViewSource` (using it for Filtering, Grouping and Sorting operations).

My `MainWindow XAML`:

```
<Window>
   <local:CustomUserControl x:Name="CustomUCDataGrid" ListToDisplay="{Binding listFromDB}"/>
<Window>
```

My `MainWindow.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<customType> listFromDB{get;set;}
    public MainWindow{
       listFromDB = GetListFromDB();
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

`CustomUserControl.xaml` looks something like:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ParentNode">
   <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ParentNode}">
      <StackPanel>
         <DataGrid x:Name="DirectDataGrid" ItemSource="{Binding ListToDisplay}"/>
         <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridWithCVS" ItemsSource="{Binding cvsList.View}"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

`CustomUserControl.xaml.cs` looks like:

```
public partial class CustomUserControl: UserControl
{
    public List<customType> ListToDisplay{
        get { return (List<customType>)GetValue(ListToDisplayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListToDisplayProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListToDisplayProperty=
            DependencyProperty.Register("ListToDisplay", typeof(List<customType>),
              typeof(CustomUserControl));

    public CollectionViewSource cvsList { get; set; }

    public CustomUserControl{
        InitializeComponent();
         cvsList = new CollectionViewSource();
         cvsList.Source = ListToDisplay;
         DataGridWithCVS.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(cvsList);
    }
}
```

Here the DataGrid with name **"DirectDataGrid"** has ***no problem*** in displaying the data supplied to it from the MainWindow, but the DataGrid with name **"DataGridWithCVS"** doesn't display any data. Couldn't find any errors while debugging.

***Things I have already Tried:***

- Define the CollectionViewSource as a StaticResource inside the CustomUserControl XAML - Can't implement this because, the UserControl doesn't use the DataContext set from the MainWindow. It uses its own DataContext without overriding the MainWindow's DataContext. (`<UserControl x:Name="ParentNode"> <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ParentNode}">...`).

Comment: Thanks @thatguy for the edit!!! I saw your answer too... I have used your method to solve another problem that I was facing in a different project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just some kind of madness :)

Leave Code Behind alone.
In your case, apart from declaring DependecyProperty, there should be nothing there.

```
<UserControl x:Name="ParentNode">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsList"
                Source="{Binding ListToDisplay, ElementName=ParentNode}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DirectDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ListToDisplay, ElementName=ParentNode}"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridWithCVS" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource cvsList}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```